# Limits of functions with holes (variables vs constants)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

It's been many years since I've done math so I've decided to take a Calculus refresher course on edx, there's the following problem in the limits section:

[image]

I'm trying to understand why $\lim_{x \to 1}f(x)$ is 1 but $\lim_{x \to 1}f(1)$ is 2. We're plugging 1 in both cases, why are the results different? Is it because in the former case we're evaluating a variable and in the latter a constant?

Similarly, $\lim_{x \to 4}f(x)$ is 2 (I'm guessing it's the same reason $\lim_{x \to 1}f(x)$ is 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the graph, $f$ is not continuous in $1$. You see indeed that $f(1) = 2$, but that when $x$ approaches $1$ (by the left or by the right), the value of $f(x)$ approaches $1$.

This means that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} = 1$. But $f(1)=2$, which is not contradictory since $f$ is not continuous in $1$.

For the same reason, when $x$ approaches $4$ (but is not equal to $4$), you see that the value of $f(x)$ approaches $2$. So $\lim_{x \rightarrow 4} = 2$, and that is independant of the value of $f(4)$ (which you don't know by the way).

Comment: But when evaluating the limit, I essentially plug 1 into $f$, right, as $x$ tends to 1? Why is this different to $f(1)$?

Comment: No, evaluating a limit is not plugging the value into $f$. It is the case only when $f$ is continuous. In general, evalutation a limit consists in looking which value $f(x)$ approaches when $x$ approaches the point you consider.

Comment: Aha, thank you, that clears it up, just for future reference, is this a general pattern of solving these kinds of problem? Check which value a function tends to and proceed from there?

Comment: Well it depends on the context. Here you have a graph, the goal of the problem is to see "visually" what is the limit. In most cases however, functions are given by formulas, and then yes, you can use algebraic properties to find the limit.